# jQuery Flipclock show print text duplicate inside interval function

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, flipclock

I'm working with [jQuery Flipclock](https://github.com/objectivehtml/FlipClock)

It's working good.
Then now I have button modify time, if I click it then the time will be change to 10 seconds and print the text into `span` info. But why the old counting value is still appear? How to print into `span` info only 10 seconds (on button click) without show the old counting value?.

```js
$('.modifytime').on('click', function() {
  countdown(10);
});


function countdown(b) {
  if (b == undefined) {
    a = 15;
  } else {
    a = 10
  }

  clock = $('.clock').FlipClock(a, {
    clockFace: 'MinuteCounter',
    countdown: true,
    autoStart: true,
    callbacks: {
      start: function() {
        $('.message').html('The clock has started!');
      },
      interval: function() {
        var time = this.factory.getTime().time;

        $('.info').html(time);
      },
      stop: function(){
        alert("Counting done");
      }
    }
  });
}

countdown();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://kms.puksiix.com/flipclock.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://kms.puksiix.com/flipclock.js"></script>

<div class="clock"></div>
<span class="info"></span>

<button class="modifytime">Modify</button>
```

**UPDATED**
If I put this script:

```
stop: function(){
    alert("Counting done");
}
```

It always show me "Counting done" even I just click the button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The documentation of that rather outdated library seems to no longer exist. However if you look through the source of the library in Github you can see there is a `stop()` method which can be called on the instance.

To retain a reference to the instance between button clicks you can store it in the `data` alongside the `.clock` element, something like this:

```js
let $clock = $('.clock');

$('.modifytime').on('click', function() {
  countdown(10);
});

function countdown(delay) {
  delay = delay || 100;
  
  // check for previous instance and stop it counting down
  let prevInstance = $clock.data('flipclock');
  if (prevInstance)
    prevInstance.stop();
  
  let clockInstance = $clock.FlipClock(delay, {
    clockFace: 'MinuteCounter',
    countdown: true,
    autoStart: true,
    callbacks: {
      start: function() {
        $('.message').html('The clock has started!');
      },
      interval: function() {
        var time = this.factory.getTime().time;
        $('.info').html(time);
      }
    }
  });

  // save new instance in element metadata
  $clock.data('flipclock', clockInstance);
}

countdown();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://kms.puksiix.com/flipclock.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://kms.puksiix.com/flipclock.js"></script>

<div class="clock"></div>
<span class="info"></span>
<button class="modifytime">Modify</button>
```

Comment: Hi just now I tested with `stop: function` (you can see my above updated post). Why it always show me "Counting Done" when I click the button.

Comment: It shows 'counting done' because you put that in the `stop` event handler. That gets called every time you stop the previous counter and start a new one.

Comment: Hi, can it possible if We remove/delete the element? So it will destroy the element then counting with the fresh counter.

Comment: Sure, call `remove()` on the existing one then `append()` a new one, making sure to initialise the flipclock again

Comment: Would you give an example with your current code? This will very helpful for me.

Comment: Just now tried the fiddle. But the counting number still show the old counter and new counter

Comment: You're right - I missed that. In which case it seems to be a limitation of the library you're using. I'd suggest finding an alternative as the one you're using is very outdated, doesn't follow good practices and is no longer updated.

Answer (score 1):

A quick perusal of the source shows you can `.stop` the existing clock before starting a new one:

```
clock.stop();
```

Add this to your countdown() function.  Snippet includes a second button to stop to show this working independently.

```js
$('.modifytime').on('click', function() {
  countdown(10);
});

$(".stop").on("click", function() { clock.stop(); });


var clock;

function countdown(b) {
  if (b == undefined) {
    a = 100;
  } else {
    a = 10
  }

  if (clock) clock.stop();

  clock = $('.clock').FlipClock(a, {
    clockFace: 'MinuteCounter',
    countdown: true,
    autoStart: true,
    callbacks: {
      start: function() {
        $('.message').html('The clock has started!');
      },
      interval: function() {
        var time = this.factory.getTime().time;

        $('.info').html(time);
      }
    }
  });
}

countdown();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://kms.puksiix.com/flipclock.css" rel="stylesheet" />
<script src="https://kms.puksiix.com/flipclock.js"></script>

<div class="clock"></div>
<span class="info"></span>

<button class="modifytime">Modify</button>
<button class="stop">Stop</button>
```

Comment: Hi just now I tested with `stop: function` (you can see my above updated post). Why it always show me "Counting Done" when I click the button.